# Получение RequestBody после десериализации в объект

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

Есть метод принимающий объект `User` как аргумент.

Spring Boot очень удобно создаёт объекты из json.
Но иногда необходимо в случае ошибки посмотреть какой же пришел json изначально.
Метод с приёмом `@RequestBody String body` и ручной десериализацией очень неудобен.

Есть ли другой способ?

```
@PostMapping("/saveNewUser")
public void saveNewUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    try{
        Hibernate.save(user);
    }catch (Exception e){
        logger.error("Произошла ошибка. Прислали json: " + ... );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В Spring Boot по умолчанию использует Jackson парсер. То есть если неверный JSON приходит на контроллер, то парсер выбрасывает [`JsonParseException`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParseException.html).

Это исключение можно обрабатывать

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(JsonParseException.class)
  public final ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> handleJsonParseException(JsonParseException ex, WebRequest request) {
    ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),
        request.getDescription(false));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
```

Comment: ErrorDetails - неизвестный класс. Какую библиотеку для этого надо подключать? И ексепшен у меня другой в таких случаях в хенлдере: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: Ну это к примеру, вы можете использовать произвольный класс. Если вы знаете как писать советы контроллеру, то для вас не должно составить труда подобрать те исключения, которые вы хотите обрабатывать.

Comment: Точно! Оказалось в переменной WebRequest request можно получить пришедший json так: String body = request.getParameterMap().keySet().iterator().next(); Спасибо!